# Is it possible to change the path to the linker for gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, segmentation-fault, cross-platform

I have a `gcc` binary which was compiled on Solaris 8. For an experiment, I've brought it over to a NetBSD 8.2 virtual machine to see if I can get it working in that environment. The compilation phase of that `gcc` appears to work successfully (i.e. `gcc -c some_program.c`), but if the linker is involved, the linker appears to generate a segmentation violation. I suspect this has something to do with the built-in linker path in `gcc`. Is there a way to alter this path without completely rebuilding the binary?

Below is the output of `gcc -v -o small small.c`, where `small.c` simply has `int main() { return 0; }`:

```
Reading specs from /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/2.95.1/specs
gcc version 2.95.1 19990816 (release)
 /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/2.95.1/cpp -lang-c -v -D__GNUC__=2 -D__GNUC_MINOR__=95 -Dsparc -Dsun -Dunix -D__svr4__ -D__SVR4 -D__sparc__ -D__sun__ -D__unix__ -D__svr4__ -D__SVR4 -D__sparc -D__sun -D__unix -Asystem(unix) -Asystem(svr4) -D__GCC_NEW_VARARGS__ -Acpu(sparc) -Amachine(sparc) small.c /var/tmp/ccibWaJl.i
GNU CPP version 2.95.1 19990816 (release) (sparc)
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 .
 .
 .
End of search list.
The following default directories have been omitted from the search path:
 /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/2.95.1/../../../../include/g++-3
End of omitted list.
 /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/2.95.1/cc1 /var/tmp/ccibWaJl.i -quiet -dumpbase small.c -version -o /var/tmp/ccCCiV6u.s
GNU C version 2.95.1 19990816 (release) (sparc-sun-solaris2.8) compiled by GNU C version 2.95.1 19990816 (release).
 /usr/ccs/bin/as -V -Qy -s -o /var/tmp/ccqr3F3G.o /var/tmp/ccCCiV6u.s
/usr/ccs/bin/as: Sun WorkShop 6 99/08/18
 /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/2.95.1/collect2 -V -Y P,/usr/ccs/lib:/usr/lib -Qy -o small /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/2.95.1/crt1.o /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/2.95.1/crti.o /usr/ccs/lib/values-Xa.o /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/2.95.1/crtbegin.o -L/usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/2.95.1 -L/usr/ccs/bin -L/usr/ccs/lib -L/usr/local/lib /var/tmp/ccqr3F3G.o -lgcc -lc -lgcc /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/2.95.1/crtend.o /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/2.95.1/crtn.o
collect2: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation Fault]
ld: Software Generation Utilities - Solaris Link Editors: 5.8-1.281
```

**Update:** For comparison, here is the output of the same compile string using the `gcc` binary on NetBSD:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/lto-wrapper
Target: sparc--netbsdelf
Configured with: /usr/src/tools/gcc/../../external/gpl3/gcc/dist/configure --target=sparc--netbsdelf --enable-long-long --enable-threads --with-bugurl=http://www.NetBSD.org/Misc/send-pr.html --with-pkgversion='NetBSD nb3 20180905' --with-system-zlib --disable-libstdcxx-dual-abi --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libstdcxx-time=rt --enable-libstdcxx-threads --with-diagnostics-color=auto-if-env --with-mpc-lib=/var/obj/mknative/sparc/usr/src/external/lgpl3/mpc/lib/libmpc --with-mpfr-lib=/var/obj/mknative/sparc/usr/src/external/lgpl3/mpfr/lib/libmpfr --with-gmp-lib=/var/obj/mknative/sparc/usr/src/external/lgpl3/gmp/lib/libgmp --with-mpc-include=/usr/src/external/lgpl3/mpc/dist/src --with-mpfr-include=/usr/src/external/lgpl3/mpfr/dist/src --with-gmp-include=/usr/src/external/lgpl3/gmp/lib/libgmp/arch/sparc --enable-tls --disable-multilib --disable-symvers --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-dual-abi --build=sparc--netbsdelf --host=sparc--netbsdelf --with-sysroot=/var/obj/mknative/sparc/usr/src/destdir.sparc
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.5.0 (nb3 20180905) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'small' '-mcpu=v7'
 /usr/libexec/cc1 -quiet -v small.c -quiet -dumpbase small.c -mcpu=v7 -auxbase small -version -o /tmp//ccZMD7zc.s
GNU C11 (nb3 20180905) version 5.5.0 (sparc--netbsdelf)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.5.0, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=46 --param ggc-min-heapsize=30704
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/gcc-5
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C11 (nb3 20180905) version 5.5.0 (sparc--netbsdelf)
    compiled by GNU C version 5.5.0, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=46 --param ggc-min-heapsize=30704
Compiler executable checksum: 2df9f867f6d360c5052229962b633018
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'small' '-mcpu=v7'
 as -v -32 -relax -o /tmp//ccXtMemo.o /tmp//ccZMD7zc.s
GNU assembler version 2.27 (sparc--netbsdelf) using BFD version (NetBSD Binutils nb1) 2.27
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'small' '-mcpu=v7'
 ld -plugin /usr/libexec/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/libexec/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp//ccyzsYKQ.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc --eh-frame-hdr -m elf32_sparc -relax -dc -dp -e __start -dynamic-linker /usr/libexec/ld.elf_so -o small /usr/lib/crt0.o /usr/lib/crti.o /usr/lib/crtbegin.o /tmp//ccXtMemo.o --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lgcc -lc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lgcc -lc /usr/lib/crtend.o /usr/lib/crtn.o
```

**Update as of 04/20/2022 5:46 PM EST:** I've installed `gcc` version 3.4.6 on my Solaris 8 virtual machine, and it appears to work there. However, transferring that binary as well as all of the necessary libraries over to NetBSD results in an immediate segmentation violation whenever the Solaris 8 `gcc` binary runs. Some other dynamically linked binaries from the Solaris 8 VM still seem functional, though.

I also attempted specifying the `-B` flag to the original 2.95.1 `gcc` binary and passing the directory containing the `collect2` executable. This seemed to have no effect on the result. Perhaps I will try to use other versions of `gcc`...

Comment: You can invoke compiler and linker separately

Comment: Oh, wait. Are you really using that ancient gcc version? Tried to update it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Regarding your first comment, you're saying that I can use the Solaris 8 linker program separately once I have the object file? For the second: you think using a newer Solaris 8 `gcc` binary would help?

Comment: I am not familiar with Solaris specifically, but I'll be surprised there is no newer GCC version for it. The version you are using is over 20 years old, if the versioning scheme is conventional, and updating it might very well fix it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Okay, I believe there is a newer `gcc` for Solaris 8; I will give that a whirl and update the OP with results.

Comment: Generally speaking, code compiled on Solaris will not run on NetBSD and vice versa.  Even assuming both machines are running the same hardware (NetBSD on SPARC, it would seem), there's no guarantee that the calling conventions are the same.  You may be lucky, but I wouldn't count on it.  There are options to control where GCC finds executables — see [Directory Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) and maybe [Spec Files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Spec-Files.html#Spec-Files).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was able to get a Solaris-8 compiled program to run perfectly on NetBSD by recompiling the NetBSD kernel with the `COMPAT_SVR4` option set. However, not all of the Solaris 8 binaries I've tested have worked. Nonetheless, once I get a newer version of Solaris 8's `gcc`, I'll check out those links and see if I have any luck. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @EugeneSh., @JonathanLeffer I've updated the OP with a brief summary of results from `gcc` 3.4.6.

Comment: The TL;DR: You appear to have the source (because of the talk about using a later gcc version) so just recompile on NetBSD and be done with it. The kernel compat layer may _not_ support _all_ needed syscalls. That's why it worked for some programs but not all. Also, for some syscalls that take a `struct` pointer (e.g. `stat`) it may not work at all. So, to verify the port of a given program, you'll need a test suite that covers 100% Otherwise, you have a program that may work for a while but may crash unpredictably. Not a robust solution, IMO

Comment: @CraigEstey Fair enough. I have a `gcc` binary that came with the NetBSD installation, and I still have the partially-working 2.95.1 `gcc`. If I can't figure out a solution to the linker problem, then I may just declare failure.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Your implied suggestion of invoking the linker manually worked! Thanks for that tip, and thanks to everyone who commented!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that invoking the linker separately, as per Eugene's suggestion in the first comment on the OP, worked. Here are the high level steps I took to get a working executable:

1. Compile the small program with `gcc -c` to get an object file.
2. Run all phases of `gcc` with `-v` to get the linker command that `gcc` is trying to run.
3. Copy the linker line of that output to a shell script and replace the respective paths to the linker as well as all of the object files involved with the correct paths.
4. Add the `-rpath` parameter to the command to cover any "`*.so` library not found" errors.
5. Run the shell script.
6. Run the produced program.

Thanks to everyone who commented on the OP as well!

Comment: I hope this is just for fun. I like forward porting ancient binaries [for fun, as a hobby]. As I mentioned before, you'd have to verify that the struct definitions match up [manual source code inspection]. And, of course, there's a later `gcc` version than 2.95.1 That version has bugs and was last current circa 2004. My home system is about five distro revs back and even I have gcc 8.3.1. Note that what you're doing may work, but it isn't the "Pythonic" way for C :-) So, caveat emptor ...

Comment: @CraigEstey Yeah this is mainly to get a rough idea of how something like this might work in other settings.